# .less and css "padding: @reference"

Tags: html, css, less, padding

I am configuring a Magento theme which uses .less files and compiles these to .css for the frontend.

And here I'm trying to change the padding on an element which is:

```scss
.pad-main {
    padding: @cpanel-home-main-block-padding;
}
```

Where could `@cpanel-home-main-block-padding` be referencing to, is this another .less file? I cannot find this, any help is appreciated.

Thank you, Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pointing to a less variable.
You could search for the name of the variable in less files.
It may be pointing to one the imported less files.

Comment: Thanks Saeed, I searched through all the .less files and managed to find this variable...